# If I have multiple answers to a question, how should I post them?

Tags: discussion

While I was answering this question ([How to distribute objects in a circular pattern on a surface (Radial Array, Polar Array)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31961/how-to-distribute-objects-in-a-circular-pattern-on-a-surface/31965#31965)), I noticed that I had several ways to answer this question I posted one of the methods I would use, but since I have several, should I post them at all, post them as a separate answer, or post them in the same answer, or something completely different?

Comment: I say, if the multiple solutions are really different (i.e. not just variations of the same basic idea), then go ahead and post multiple answers.  SE gives the option of doing so, so I say use it!  There's no law of SE that says "you must always choose the option that gets you the least reputation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do want you have time for.

The one reason I don't like to see tonnes of solutions in 1 answer is because it makes it hard to see which of the answers is voted for more often. ie, which is proving to be most useful.

Lumping them together has that problem, but people also don't like to see multiple answer by one person - and I think wrongly justify their averse reaction to multi answers as an attempt by the answerer to 'milk the cash cow' for points.

However, for this question about the circular array, it has been asked in so many forms already, and his been given unique (but similar) answers in most cases. I propose that we do a canonical answer instead because it's a very basic and useful question with some convoluted responses in other threads.

Comment: Yeah, if it wasn't for the rep, I would think it would be to just answer multiple times.

Comment: On your last point, do you mean a wiki similar to the gpu setup one found here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles?

Comment: So in general, you would just say keep it all in one answer unless it becomes fairly large and it's hard to find the part that is needed?

Comment: We don't need to give full blown answers either, in general people are quite happy with the minimal answer if it lets them piece together the rest themselves they get a sense of accomplishment too (and neural training to solve own problems). I like to keep that in mind, sometimes we do a disservice by being too complete in our answers. Some topics pop up so often that a dedicated wiki page / or community answer is useful. I will add my answer to that question as the other answers in the past have bothered me a lot.